# bash get 2nd JSON record with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to get the lastest version of "spip"
For that, I can use a JSON output from https://www.spip.net/spip_loader.api but I don't know how to get the 2nd record key (4.2.5) in bash with jq.

```
$ wget -q -O- https://www.spip.net/spip_loader.api | jq '.versions'
{
  "dev": "spip/dev/spip-master.zip",
  "4.2.5": "spip/archives/spip-v4.2.5.zip",
  "4.1.12": "spip/archives/spip-v4.1.12.zip",
  "4.0.11": "spip/archives/spip-v4.0.11.zip",
  "3.2.19": "spip/archives/spip-v3.2.19.zip"
}
```

I could just get 3rd line with `| sed -n '3p'` but I don't find it very clean and I think that using jq completely would be more suitable.

I admit that it's more out of curiosity than out of need since I can do otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `keys_unsorted` to get a list of keys in representation order, then take the second one (at index 1):

```bash
jq -r '.versions | keys_unsorted[1]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IyOq-fNU7R8)

Getting "the lastest version" highly depends on how the version numbers are constructed. Your sample suggests that considering numbers only will suffice. So, strip consecutive digits from the keys, turn them into numbers, and get the maximum by that:

```bash
jq -r '.versions | keys_unsorted | max_by([scan("\\d+") | tonumber])'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fZ4oRDahbpD)

Output:

```
4.2.5
```

Comment: For `max_by`, you don't need "unsorted" (but it doesn't hurt).

Comment: @choroba Just using `keys` is shorter, of course, but I *feels like* the extra sorting makes it less efficient. Never took the time to look up how it's actually implemented.

Comment: Perfect, and understood.

Answer (score 2):

This will produce both version and path :

```
wget -q -O- https://www.spip.net/spip_loader.api |
  jq -r '.versions | to_entries
        | max_by(.key | [scan("\\d+") | tonumber])
        | "\(.key) \(.value)"'
# Output: 4.2.5 spip/archives/spip-v4.2.5.zip
```